# SQL variable in IF exists

Tags: mysql

I can't figure out the correct way to assign query output into a variable that i could later use in an INSERT clause.

The error I get is

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;     check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right     syntax to use near 'SET @lennuid = (select lend_id from lend where     sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_' at line 8

I've tried looking at every guide on variables in SQL but none of them could help me solve this.

Iam using the below  code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proov(
in_kuhu varchar(50), in_nimi1 varchar(50), in_nimi2 varchar(50), in_adre varchar(50), in_telo varchar(20), in_email varchar(100), in_date date)
BEGIN
DECLARE viga INTEGER DEFAULT 0 ;
DECLARE lennuid INT;
START TRANSACTION;
IF exists (
SET @lennuid = (select lend_id from lend where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_date)) THEN
INSERT INTO broneering
(lend_id, bron_aeg, eesnim, perenimi, aadress, telefon, email)
VALUES
(lennuid, NOW(), in_nimi1, in_nimi2, in_adre, in_telo, in_email);
ELSE
set viga=1;
SELECT 'Muudatus ebaonnestus ',viga;
END IF;
IF viga=0 then
COMMIT;
select 'korras';
ELSE
select 'tagasi';
ROLLBACK;
END IF;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `SELECT INTO`:

```
select lend_id into @lennuid
from lend 
where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_date;
```

Alternatively:

```
select @lennuid := lend_id
from lend 
where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_date;
```

Either way works the same, then you can use that variable however you like...

In your particular example, though, the problem is actually how your `exists` is being used along with the `set`. To fix this, use the following:

```
IF exists (select lend_id from lend where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_date) THEN ...
```

What the problem here is, is you were setting a variable with `SET` inside of the `EXISTS` check.

Or you could do your select first as a `COUNT` into a numeric variable:

```
DECLARE cnt INTEGER;
select Count(lend_id) into @cnt 
from lend 
where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu 
   and kuupaev=in_date;

IF @cnt > 0 THEN

END IF;
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be the problem, I also tried Arulkumar's solution but still no progress, I'll keep trying.

Comment: Updated the answer. There was a different problem aside from your request to set values to a variable from a select statement. See the last example in my answer above.

Comment: Yep, worked after I culled some IF statements and rearranged the whole thing a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`THEN` causing the issue.

```
IF exists (
SET @lennuid = (select lend_id from lend where sihtpunkt=in_kuhu AND kuupaev=in_date)) 
BEGIN  -- Instead of THEN use BEGIN , END
    INSERT INTO broneering
    (lend_id, bron_aeg, eesnim, perenimi, aadress, telefon, email)
    VALUES 
    (lennuid, NOW(), in_nimi1, in_nimi2, in_adre, in_telo, in_email);
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    set viga=1;
    SELECT 'Muudatus ebaonnestus ',viga;
END
END IF;
```

Comment: Still keeps giving the same error even when I replace WHEN with BEGIN.
...right syntax to use near 'SET lennuid = ... Maybe I'm missing something that should precede the SET lennuid part?